# Passing objects between fragments using parcelable in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

How do you do that? I have the object class implementing parcelable but i don't know what to do for sending the object from one fragment to another one. Help me please.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Share your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing data between fragments is always painful, as both fragments need to define same interface description and the owner activity must bind two together.

And also need to handle the conditions like other fragment not created or not visible

But with new ViewModel, our life become easy to deal with fragment communication. All we have to do is just create a common ViewModel using the activity scope to handle the communication.

Let’s take an example where as in one fragment we need to show list of news articles , and another to show details of the selected news article.

Step1:- Create the Article model class.

```
public class Article {
    private int articleID;
    private String articleName;
    private String details;

    public int getArticleID() {
        return articleID;
    }

    public void setArticleID(int articleID) {
        this.articleID = articleID;
    }

    public String getArticleName() {
        return articleName;
    }

    public void setArticleName(String articleName) {
        this.articleName = articleName;
    }

    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(String details) {
        this.details = details;
    }
}
```

Step2:- Create a ArticleViewModel which holds the objects.

```
public class ArticleViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private LiveData<List<Article>> articleList;

    private final MutableLiveData<Article> selectedArticle = new MutableLiveData<Article>();

    public MutableLiveData<Article> getSelectedArticle() {
        return selectedArticle;
    }

    public void setSelectedArticle(Article article) {
        selectedArticle.setValue(article);
    }

    public LiveData<List<Article>> getArticleList() {
        return articleList;
    }

    public void loadArticles() {
        // fetch articles here asynchronously
    }

}

Step3:- Create a ArticleListFragment which take care of your list.



 public class ArticleListFragment extends Fragment {
        private SharedViewModel model;
        public void onActivityCreated() {
            ArticleViewModel model =         ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(ArticleViewModel.class);
                listItemSelector.setOnClickListener(article -> {
                model.setSelectedArticle(article);
           });
        }
    }
```

Step4:- Create your ArticleDetailFragment to show details of article

```
public class ArticleDetailFragment extends LifecycleFragment {
    public void onActivityCreated() {
        ArticleViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(ArticleViewModel.class);
        model.getSelectedArticle().observe(this, { article ->
                // update UI
        });
    }
}
```

If you observe, both fragments are using getActivity() while getting the ViewModelProviders. Means both fragments receive same ArticleViewModel instance, which is scoped to your parent Activity.

Its just that simple and we get more benefits like

Your Activity no need to worry about this communication
Even one fragment get destroyed, other one use the data in ViewModel.
Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the navGraph to share data between fragments.It's easy.